# Task.Run(method group) vs. Task.Run(lambda)

Tags: .net, asynchronous, lambda, async-await, task-parallel-library

I need to know the difference between these three ways of spinning up a Task using the TPL:

`Task.Run(() => _client.RunClient());`

vs.

`Task.Run(_client.RunClient);`

vs.

`Task.Run(async () => await _client.RunClient());`

Let's say I have the following class structure:

```
public class Controller {

  private _client = new Client();

  ...

  public async Task StartClientA() {
    await Task.Run(_client.RunClient);
  }

  public async Task StartClientB() {
    await Task.Run(() => _client.RunClient());
  }

  public async Task StartClientC() {
    await Task.Run(async () => await _client.RunClient());
  }
}
```

Then, in the client, here are the method signatures for each of StartClientA, StartClientB, and StartClientC:

```
public async Task StartClientA() {
  ...
}

public async Task StartClientB() {
  ...
}

public async Task StartClientC() {
  ...
}
```

Now, what's the difference between how I'm calling RunClient in each of these methods?

What's confusing to me is what happens to the code that comes after:

`await Task.Run(...)`

Does Task.Run return immediately, and the function continues executing?  Or does Task.Run complete only when the method _client.RunClient completes?  What is _client.RunClient is in a while(true) loop and never exits?  How does that impact each of these methods of spinning up a thread?

What is best practice around these different ways of invoking a Task?  Do I await the lambda?  Do I await the Task.Run?  Do I not await _client.RunClient?

Sorry for all the questions in one post.  I'm trying to understand these different behaviors so I can pick the one that makes the most sense.  I've read about async/await a lot, and this is one question I can't seem to find an answer to.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to know the difference between these three ways of spinning up a Task

```
Task.Run(() => _client.RunClient());
Task.Run(_client.RunClient);
Task.Run(async () => await _client.RunClient());
```

These are all pretty much the same. The first one passes a lambda in, which is converted to a delegate; the second one passes a method group in, which is converted to a delegate; the third one passes a lambda in, which is converted to a delegate that has an `async` state machine.

But in terms of semantics, they're all practically the same. The third one has slightly more overhead, but most likely the amount of overhead is immeasurably small in your actual application.

> Does Task.Run return immediately, and the function continues executing?

`Task.Run` immediately returns a `Task`.

> Or does Task.Run complete only when the method _client.RunClient completes?

That depends on what you mean by the `Task.Run` completing. It returns a task immediately, but when a method returns a task, then that task represents the execution of that method. The task returned by `Task.Run` will complete when `RunClient` completes.

> What is _client.RunClient is in a while(true) loop and never exits? How does that impact each of these methods of spinning up a thread?

Then the task returned by `Task.Run` will never complete.

> What is best practice around these different ways of invoking a Task? Do I await the lambda? Do I await the Task.Run? Do I not await _client.RunClient?

1. `await` tasks. Unless you shouldn't (e.g., the task doesn't complete).
2. [Don't use `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html). Unless you need to (e.g., moving CPU-bound code off the UI thread, or enforcing a thread pool context).
3. Do not [elide `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). Unless it's a trivial method, like the lambda in this example.

Comment: thank you Stephen.  appreciate the thorough response.